# Which Android virtual device is based on ARM system image?

Tags: android-emulator, android-studio, arm-processors

Android Studio has a feature where you can emulate an Android device -- tablet, phone, etc. -- but it crashes the virtual machine (Ubuntu) I am using.  Depending on which VM platform I am using, it sometimes lets me know what went wrong.  Here are the four options:

> **Troubleshoot**
>
> Unfortunately, your computer does not support hardware accelerated virtualization.
> Here are some of your options:
> 1) Use a physical device for testing
> 2) Develop on a Windows/OSX computer with an Intel processor that supports VT-x and NX
> 3) Develop on a Linux computer that supports VT-x or SVM
> 4) Use an Android Virtual Device based on an ARM system image
> (This is 10x slower than hardware accelerated virtualization)

I like the fourth one.  So, which Android virtual device is based on ARM system image?

*Original pop-up dialog:*

[image: Original pop-up dialog]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not recommended due to performance issues, the Android SDK manager still provides ARM system images for the Android SDK emulator:

1. Open "Virtual Device Manager"
2. Click the "Create device" button
3. On "Select Hardware", select an existing device or create a new one, then click the "Next" button
4. On "System Image", switch to the "Other Images" tab
5. Download and select an ARM system image (ABI starting with "arm"), then click the "Next" button
6. Click the "Finish" button to create a new virtual device with an ARM system image

It is also possible to download the system images directly from the SDK Manager:

1. Open "SDK Manager" (Appearance & Behavior - System Settings - Android SDK)
2. Switch to the "SDK Platforms" tab (if it's not selected by default)
3. Tick the "Show Package Details" checkbox
4. Under the Android version to be used, expand the details
5. Tick respective ARM system images to download (e.g. "ARM 64 v8a System Image")
6. Click the "OK" button