# Trying to buy an app on a degoogled device. Why is the app "not compatible with your device"?

Tags: google-play-store, emulators, compatibility

I have a degoogled lineageos phone. I'd like to be able to play "A dance of fire and ice" and "cytus" on this device.

If I have previously purchased these apps, I think I should be able to install them through the aurora store (Or worst case, extract an apk from another device and install it). The only problem is that I don't actually own any android devices with gapps to purchase these apps on, and the play store web interface doesn't let me purchase an app if I am not logged in on any eligible devices.

Therefore I decided to set up a waydroid install with gapps, to try and get this stuff to work. However, after having done this, and navigating to the store page I see: "This app won't work for your device", and when I go to the web interface, I see the following:

[image]

Of course android is being its usual opaque self, and not actually telling me why it "won't work on my device".

I think I might be able to fix this by setting up waydroid in such a way that the playstore thinks that my device is in fact compatible with this app, just that I have no idea what it wants me to do for it to accept this app. Is the screen resolution wrong? Wrong android version? Something else entirely?

I already purchased a play store gift card which I can't return anymore. Therefore there is no use in giving up because something might not work. I was willing to take the gamble when I bought that card in the first place anyways

Comment: The app is not paid, but uses in-app purchases. In-app purchases require Google services to work. Not sure what happens if the app tries to access Google services to check the license and your in-app purchases and it does not exists. A crash is very likely.

Comment: A dance of fire and ice is paid, also, I should have said cytus II instead of cytus, cytus is indeed not paid but has in app purchases.

Comment: For third party apps you should better directly link to the PlayStore entry. Your screen shot shows that it has in-app purchases (and it is additionally a paid app). Note that Google recommends for paid apps to perform a license check at start-up to avoid illegal distribution of paid APK files. This license check is similar to an in-app purchase check and for both AFAIK Google services are needed. https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing

Comment: The link to the playstore entry:
https://play.google.com/store/search?q=a+dance+of+fire+and+ice&c=apps
Also, I know very well that the resulting apk might not work. I just want to try it, I already purchased the gift card anyways.

Comment: You can try to install Android Emulator from Android SDK. Google provides emulator images with built-in Google services and Play store. Buying apps in the emulator should be possible. It would be at least worth a try if the app you want is available in that environment or not.

Comment: Based on the screenshot, it seems Waydroid is using an *x86* image which is [very rare](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/248822/44325) nowadays, and rarely supported on games that depend on native libraries. Consider [trying an ARM image](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/247963/44325) instead.

Comment: I guess it makes sense that x86 would cause compatibility issues, started a pixel 2 through android studio, which seemed to let me purchase the app. The aurora store let me install the app on my main device, and I am now successfully playing a dance of fire and ice on my degoogled phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Robert](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/2241/robert)'s comment seems to have fixed it (I used the emulator built into android studio, which I happened to have already installed, with a device that has the play store installed). I guess the reason waydroid didn't work is because it was on an x86_64 device, like [Andrew T.](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/44325/andrew-t) mentioned.

Either way, I managed to couple that emulated device to my phone, and I was then able to purchase a dance of fire and ice through the google play web interface. After doing this, I could just install the app through aurora, on which I am logged in with my google account. This works, and I am now happily playing a dance of fire and ice on my degoogled device. Though I wouldn't be surprised if not all apps allow you to just run them like that without gapps.

update:
tried cytus II as well, this one didn't work.